# ANSIBLE: Split function not removing the '\r' carriage return from string

Tags: split, ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

I have a local txt file called file-names.txt that contains a list of filenames

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

In my ansible-playbook I'm registering the file contents of file-name.txt using the slurp module.
And setting a fact named `files_names`.

```
tasks:
 - name: Getting the file
   ansible.builtin.slurp:
    src: file-name.txt
   register: file_names
 - name: Saving the file names
   set_fact: 
     file_name_list: "{{ (file_name['content] | b64decode | trim ).split('\r\n') }}"
```

I want the `file_name_list` fact to be a list just containing the file names. but some how split function is not able to remove the `'\r'` from the file names and I get the following results

```
ok: [localhost] => {
  "ansible_facts":{
     "file_name_list": [
       "file1.txt\r",
       "file2.txt\r",
       "file3.txt"       
      ]
  },
  "changed": false
}
```

How can I remove the carriage return `'\r'` from each element of the array so that `file_name_list` looks like

```
ok: [localhost] => {
  "ansible_facts":{
     "file_name_list": [
       "file1.txt",
       "file2.txt",
       "file3.txt"       
      ]
  },
  "changed": false
}
```

PS: file-name.txt was made on a Windows machine, that's why there is a carriage return included in each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `trim` filter seems to be removing the final `\r` from the list of files on `file3.txt`. So instead of using `trim` before splitting, we can trim each `item` after splitting the filenames with `\r`.

Something like below should do the trick:

```yaml
    - name: saving the file names
      set_fact:
        filename_list: "{{ filename_list|default([]) + [ item|trim ] }}"
      with_items: "{{ (filenames.content|b64decode).split('\r') }}"
    - name: show the filenames
      debug:
        var: filename_list
```

This should produce:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "filename_list": [
        "file1.txt",
        "file2.txt",
        "file3.txt"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to remove the line breaker character '\n' from the result of lookup() module in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016123/how-to-remove-the-line-breaker-character-n-from-the-result-of-lookup-module)
`"{{  some_string| regex_replace('[\\r\\n]+','\n') }}"`